# Triggering a controller's "actions" from another controller

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I need to trigger an action's method in my `Summary` controller from `MyController`'s `handleUpdate` method.

`MyController`:

```
MyController = MyController.extend({

  needs: ['application', 'Summary'],    

  handleUpdate: function() {
    var controller = this;

    Ember.run.later(function() {
      ...
      ...
    }.bind(this), 100);
  }.observes('isUpdating')
}
```

`Update` controller:

```
SummaryController.reopen({
  actions: {
    update: function(source, callback) {
    ...
    ...
    }
  }
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grab the controller instance then use the method `send` to trigger the action.

```
MyController = MyController.extend({

  needs: ['application', 'summary'],    

  handleUpdate: function() {
    var controller = this,
        summaryController = this.get('controllers.summary');

    summaryController.send('update');

    Ember.run.later(function() {
      ...
      ...
    }.bind(this), 100);
  }.observes('isUpdating')
}
```

Comment: Well, that answered my question, but it didnt solve the problem I had in my App. I'll scratch that one off the list and its time to look somewhere else. haha Thanks!